# RoR. Styling a helper method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to style a helper method. The method works fine but html_safe (or how I have done it here) does not work to style it. I tried other variations as well like putting html_safe after .to_s, didn't work either.

Here is my latest approach.

```
def tweeted_text(counted)
      if current_user.tweets.count == 1
       first = "<b>current_user.tweets.count.to_s</b>" + " Tweet"
       first.html_safe 
      else 
       second = "<b>current_user.tweets.count.to_s</b>" + " Tweets"
       second.html_safe
    end
end
```

In my view

```
<%= tweeted_text(@counted) %>
```

What would be an appropriate way to go about styling my helper?
ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

```rb
   def tweeted_text
     result = "<b>#{current_user.tweets.count}</b> Tweet"
     result = result + "s" if current_user.tweets.count > 1
     result.html_safe
   end
```